# Gitlab CI: Trigger different child pipelines from parent pipeline based on directory of changes

Tags: gitlab

I would like to use Parent\Child pipilens https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html in this way.
I have this source structure:

```
- backend
--- .gitlab-ci.yml
--- src
- frontend
--- .gitlab-ci.yml
--- src
-.gitlab-ci.yml
```

I want to trigger backend or frontend .gitlab-ci.yml based on the path where new commit happens: if it happend on frontend, **only** frontend.gitlab-ci.yml should be used for build\publish.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify to execute different pipelines based on where the changes in the code occurred using the `only: changes` configuration documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#onlychangesexceptchanges).

You can therefor specify to execute a pipeline `frontend` only if changes happen within the `frontend` folder (analog for `backend).

You can use the `include: local` feature (documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includelocal)) to include the `frontend/.gitlab-ci.yml`-file within the pipeline for the frontend that is defined in the root `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
For examples on how to exactly configure the pipeline so that it triggers a configuration provided in a local file, please see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#examples).

Parent-child pipelines also support the `only: changes` configuration as documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html).